# Designing a database for a system with many subcomponents

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I am trying to figure out how to design a database for an application I am developing. I just want to use it as a datastore for saving and accessing configuration parameters. I've never designed a database before.

My application configures settings for a system with many components. Some of the components are unique, and some have subcomponents. Each component has a number of parameters, some of which are single values and others which contain a variable number of records.

I could represent the system like this:

```
<System>
    <A P1="" P2="">
        <E P3="" P4="" P5="" P6="" />
        <F P7="" P8="" P9="" P10="" />
        <G>
            <H>123</H>
            <H>123</H>
            <H>123</H>
            <H>123</H>
            <H>123</H>
        </G>
    </A>
    <B P1="" P2="">
        <E P3="" P4="" P5="" P6="" />
        <F P7="" P8="" P9="" P10="" />
        <G>
            <H>123</H>
            <H>123</H>
            <H>123</H>
        </G>
    </B>
    <C P1="" P2="">
        <E P11="" P12="" P13="" P14="" />
        <I P15="" P16="" P17="" P18="" P19="" />
    </C>
    <D>
        <E P11="" P12="" P13="" P14="" />
        <I P15="" P16="" P17="" P18="" P19="" />
    </D>
</System>
```

I'm not sure how this would be represented in tables and columns. What approach should I use to convert this into a relational database model?

Answer (score 0):

The tag attributes will convert into table columns. Every sub component is linked by a foreign key. That could be done with one table.

```
// from scratch

create table system (
    id char(1)
    parent char(1)
    p1 char(1)
    p2 char(1)
    p3 char(1)
    p4 char(1)
    p5 char(1)
);

insert into table system values("A",null,"","",null,null,null);
insert into table system values("E","A","","","","",null);
insert into table system values("F","A","","","","",null);
insert into table system values("G","A",null,null,null,null,null);
insert into table system values("H","G","123",null,null,null,null);
insert into table system values("H","G","123",null,null,null,null);
insert into table system values("H","G","123",null,null,null,null);
insert into table system values("H","G","123",null,null,null,null);
insert into table system values("H","G","123",null,null,null,null);
...
```

Comment: You've simplified a bit, right? I have multiple instances of E and F with different values, so those would be additional rows with different parents? Also the parameters on A are not the same as the parameters on E and F, so with this design my table would have hundreds or thousands of columns.

Comment: Ok, you didn't mentioned that before. Then, what is the problem with the XML notation. When all datasets might be diferent, then maybe a relational model is not the best.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest an alternative to the relational model? I am completely new to this.

Comment: `My application configures settings for a system with many components.` How many 100, 1000, 1000000000 ? What is your progr. language ?

Comment: Hundreds of components. I'm using C#.

Comment: I don't know C#, but as your data is not very homgenous maybe you can go with a [NoSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net) db.